# Wordpress Disable User Account?

Tags: wordpress

I want to disable a user's account. When the user's account is disabled then the user should not able to login.

How can I disable user's accounts?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Well you could just delete it. Alternatively, go to the **Users** dashboard panel and change the user's role to "-- No role for this site --"

[image]

Comment: If the author has published articles on the site, you might feel unsure what happens to the "by: " display if the account is deleted. Also, you may want to suspend the account temporarily, or create them beforehand but enable them when it's settled which team members will do what.

Comment: Setting "No role for this site" works well. After a user logs in they will see `Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.` at `/wp-admin`. To disable a user with [WP-CLI](https://wp-cli.org/) run `wp user update "${id:?}" --role=""`

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search gave me the following plugin:

> ### [Disable Users](http://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-users/)
>
> Once installed and activated, a checkbox appears on the user profile settings (only for admins). When checked, the users account will be disabled and they will be unable to login with the account. If they try to login, they are instantly logged out and redirected to the login page with a message that notifies them their account is disabled.

I think it's what you are looking for!

Comment: Overkill to use a plugin to accomplish this

Answer (score -1):

You can create a temporary user or disable user using the following plugin:

> ### [Temporary access for users](https://wordpress.org/plugins/temporary-access-for-users/)
>
> Temporary Access for users plugins creates the temporary user. If the admin wants to create a temporary user for some limited period of time like give temporary login to a user then this plugin is helpful to you.